# Uniform initialization doesn't work for initialization parent object in ctor

Tags: c++, c++11

Suppose I have a struct:

```
struct A 
{
    int i;
};
```

I can init it as:

```
A a{1};
```

Now I have a derived class:

```
struct B : public A
{
     B(int _i) : A{_i} {};
};
```

But I have a compilation error in B struct ctor:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘A(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)’
```

Compiler is gcc-4.6 (SUSE Linux) 4.6.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your code; it is simply that your compiler doesn't support all of the required C++11 features.

Your constructor compiles fine with gcc 4.7.0.

Comment: Ok, it seems time to upgrate :)